# add element to jquery's accordion widget

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jquery-ui accordion widget listing project parts which works fine (they are also sortable). But a user might add an project part by using a html input element.

I would like to prepend that new element to the accordion widget.

My approach is the following: destroy the accordion and sortable widget, then clone the first element of the widget and prepend it to element being cloned so the new element will be the first. After that just make the widget again accordion and sortable.

**It does recreate the widget, but it doesn't include the added element! And I don't see why not...**

The html being converted to a widget:

```
    <div id="accordion">
        <div>
            <h3><a href="#">Part</a></h3>
            <div>
                Some explaining text
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The javascript/jquery which makes the accordion on first load and also makes the sortable and accordion working good together (stop function):

```
var stop = false;
$('#accordion h3').click(function(e) {
    if (stop) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        stop = false;
    }
});
$('#accordion')
    .accordion({
        header: '> div > h3',
        fillSpace: true
     })
     .sortable({
         axis: 'y',
         handle: 'h3',
         stop: function() {
             stop = true;
     }
});
```

The javascript that clones and prepends the element to the widget and recreates the widget:

```
$('#accordion').accordion("destroy").sortable("destroy");
$("#accordion > div:first").clone().prependTo("#accordion > div:first");
$('#accordion')
    .accordion({
        header: '> div > h3',
        fillSpace: true
    })
    .sortable({
        axis: 'y',
        handle: 'h3',
        stop: function() {
            stop = true;
        }
     });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, sometimes the solution can be very obvious. The problem was lying in using the prependTo() function. It should be: insertBefore() /Solved